# Show multiple records from two tables using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

So I have two tables:

```
Samochod (id, FK id of silnik, model)
Silnik (id, capacity)
```

Now I want to list all my cars (all information from table "Samochod"). I tried something like this:

```
public List<Samochod> listuj() {
    List<Samochod> samochodList = new ArrayList<Samochod>();
    String query = "select * from samochod";
    samochodList = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Samochod.class));
    return samochodList;
}
```

But I got en error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'pl.edu.lab1.Silnik'...
```

Somebody have idea how can I take capacity from table "Silnik"? Because I want to print model and capacity. For example I have in data base:

```
Samochod: id = 1, id of silnik = 3, model = "Hyundai"
Silnik: id = 3, capacity = 1.4
```

So I want to print "Hyundai 1.4".

Anybody have some idea how can I do this?

@edit

Photos of my tables structure:
Samochod:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/CFtnIQv.png]

Silnik ("pojemnosc" = "capacity"):
[image: http://i.imgur.com/7NsJ5B9.png]

Relations:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/946ENz7.png]

Comment: can you post your entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silnik field on class Samochod is of type Silnik. But on database is Integer.
You need change type of  silnik  to integer or write [you own BeanPropertyRowMapper](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) .

Comment: Do you know maybe some easy tutorial how can I do it?

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.